# how to do different tooltips depending on data with Meteor Blaze and Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, meteor-blaze

I'm using Meteor Blaze and Bootstrap 3 to display an img with a tooltip on mouseover. It works fine with a static tooltip text:

```
<img class="socialMediaIcon" src={{iconPath}} data-toggle="tooltip"
     data-placement="right" title={{tooltip}} />
```

but I want to dynamically change the tooltip depending on the value of a Collection document field.

I've created a template helper to generate the desired text:

```
Template.SocialMedia.helpers({
  getSocialMediaIconTooltip: function(service) {
    console.log(">>>>>> Tooltip service =", service);
    var smsdata = socialMediaSystem.findOne({service: service});
    if (!smsdata.active)
      return smsData.tooltip;
    else {
      var smudata = socialMediaUser.findOne({accountId: Meteor.user()._id, service: service});
      if (smudata)
        return "Disconnect " + smsData.tooltip;
      else
        return "Connect " + smsData.tooltip;
    }
  },
```

and I'm calling it with:

```
<img class="socialMediaIcon" src={{iconPath}} data-toggle="tooltip"
     data-placement="right" title={{getSocialMediaIconTooltip name}} />
```

where "name" is a field in the open document (the code is inside a {{#each}} loop). "name" is non-blank and is used successfully later in the #each block. "getSocialMediaIconTooltip" never gets called and no tooltip appears. I've used this argument passing syntax in other places that work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper might be throwing an error, and in Blaze templates this means blank output (i.e. no tooltip). Check the browser console for error messages.

Your helper refers to both `smsdata` and `smsData`. Is that correct, or is `smsData` an invalid reference?

Comment: Sometimes it just takes someone else to make a suggestion that causes you to look closer at the code. I wrapped the handler in a try/catch and `smsData` is undefined. Spelled wrong, should be `smsdata` in lines 6, 10, and 12. Also, in the findOne (line 5) the key name is `subname`, not `service`. Works like a charm now, thanks @Alex for the prod. Some days I just feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Typos on my part, see comment above. The corrected code for reference:

```
Template.SocialMedia.helpers({
  getSocialMediaIconTooltip: function(service) {
  try {
    const smsdata = socialMediaSystem.findOne({subname: service});
    if (smsdata.active == false)
      return smsdata.tooltip;
    else {
      const smudata = socialMediaUser.findOne({accountId: Meteor.user()._id, service: service});
      if (smudata)
        return "Disconnect " + smsdata.tooltip;
      else
        return "Connect " + smsdata.tooltip;
    }
  } catch(ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  }
  },
```